# Is there a way to constexpr check if a class has any accessible constructor at all?

Tags: c++

There is `std::is_constructible` and its variants (for copy, move and default constructor).

However, is there a way to do a constexpr check whether an object can be constructed at all?

Comment: You mean something like: `template<typename T>
constexpr bool checkAccessibleCtor()
{
    return std::is_default_constructible<T>::value && 
        std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value && 
        std::is_move_constructible<T>::value;
}`?

Comment: You can check whether a constructor (or anything else for that matter) can be called with a specific concrete set of arguments. You can combine such checks as normal boolean expressions to form a more complex check. If the only constructor is `Foo::Foo(Bar, const Baz&)`, and you don't know about `Bar` and `Baz` beforehand, you cannot find out whether `Foo` is constructible.

Comment: How would you expect to use this? Because that check seems pointless.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to do a constexpr check whether an object can be constructed at all?

You can write a `constexpr` function and then add different checks(`is_default_constructible` etc) as shown below:

```
class C 
{
    public:
       C() = default;
};
class C2
{
    public:
     C2() {}
    private:
     C2(const C2&){}
};
template<typename T>
constexpr bool checkAccessibleCtor()
{
    //write checks here according to your need
    return std::is_default_constructible<T>::value && 
        std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value && 
        std::is_move_constructible<T>::value;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << checkAccessibleCtor<C>()<<std::endl;   //print 1
    std::cout << checkAccessibleCtor<C2>()<<std::endl; //prints 0
}
```